# How to POST a photo while passing cookies with 'fetch' in React?

Tags: reactjs, post, cookies, fetch

I'm currently trying to allow a user to upload a selected image from your machine to be POST'ed to a 3rd party API. The 3rd party API would only properly accept the photo if the user is authenticated through an existing cookie.

I am unable to get my fetch function to POST the image, but am able to successfully accomplish this in Postman by providing only the Cookie and the file.

When I try to post, I get a 400 and sometimes an error like: `body stream already read`.

Is there something I can do to make this request work? Thanks a ton!

```js
const formData = new FormData();
//this.state.selectedFile would be the image the user selected
formData.append('photo', this.state.selectedFile);

fetch(someUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  credentials: 'include'
})
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(successRes => {
    console.log('Success (Posting Image):', successRes);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error (Posting Image):', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to POST a photo while passing cookies with 'fetch' in React?

To answer your question, to ensure cookies are present you need to have `credentials: 'include'` which is exactly what you have in your code.

## More

> When I try to post, I get a 400 and sometimes an error like: body stream already read.

Two different errors. 
* 400 means: some client error. Either the server is misconfigured or your body payload is not what the server expected 
* `body stream already read` you get that when you try to read the same stream twice e.g.`.json`

Neither of these errors exist in the code you posted.